# Replace links in the text by the rule

Tags: php, regex, string, str-replace, preg-match-all

I have a text, and I want to replace all "www.domain.com" with no "?" symbol.

> www.domain.com dsa dsad sad sad sa domain.com asdasds adas dsa
>   www.domain.com/someurl/?d sad sadsad www.domain.com/someurl/ asd asd
>   sa www.domain.com?id=123 sd asdsa d

So I am searching the text with the `preg_match_all()`, and find all links without "?". Run the loop and when I run `str_replace()` it replaces all of the "domain.com" at one time, even the one with the "?" and on the next iteration it add more "add_text" to replaced domain.com, so I get the situation with "domain.com?add_text?add_text" and so on. I have the start position of the text I want to replace from `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`, but don't know if it helps me somehow.
Thanks

```
$post_content = 'www.domain.com dsa dsad sad sad sa
domain.com asdasds adas dsa
www.domain.com/someurl/?d sad sadsad
www.domain.com/someurl/ asd asd sa
www.domain.com?id=123 sd asdsa d'.'<hr>';

     $pattern = '#(www\.|https?:\/\/)?(domain.com)\S*#i';
                if($num_found = preg_match_all($pattern, $post_content, $out, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
                {
                  if ($num_found>0){
                    foreach ($out[0] as $k => $v) {
                        if (strpos($v, '?') !== false) {
                            //skip
                        }else{
    //replace
                            $post_content = str_replace($v, $v.'?add_text, $post_content);
                        }
                    }
                  }
                }
```

**Input:**

> www.domain.com dsa dsad sad sad sa domain.com asdasds adas dsa
>   www.domain.com/someurl/?d sad sadsad www.domain.com/someurl/ asd asd
>   sa www.domain.com?id=123 sd asdsa d

**Expected Output:**

> www.domain.com?add_text dsa dsad sad sad sa domain.com?add_text
>   asdasds adas dsa www.domain.com/someurl/?d sad sadsad
>   www.domain.com/someurl/?add_text asd asd sa www.domain.com?id=123 sd
>   asdsa d

So every URL have a some get param. Every URL with no "?" (get) must be with ?add_text, if there is already a ?something just skip it.

Comment: Can you please share your input and expected output?

Comment: @SahilGulati Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fundamentally flawed, as you're not taking into account substrings when replacing. You'd likely end up with data being replaced multiple times and getting corrupted. Try using [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead:

```
<?php
$post_content = 'www.domain.com dsa dsad sad sad sa
domain.com asdasds adas dsa
www.domain.com/someurl/?d sad sadsad
www.domain.com/someurl/ asd asd sa
www.domain.com?id=123 sd asdsa d'.'<hr>';
$pattern = '/((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?domain\.com(?!\S*\?))(\S*)/im';
$post_content = preg_replace($pattern, "$1$2?add_text", $post_content);
echo $post_content;
```

The regular expression gets a bit tricky, with negative lookahead assertion checking for no question marks. [The breakdown is here](https://regex101.com/r/gwNpfU/2).

Answer (score 2):

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/776373)

**Regex:** `((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.com)(?!\/|\?)|(?:https?:\/\/)?(www\.?[a-zA-Z]+.com\/(?:[^\/]+\/)*)`

`((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.com)(?!\/|\?)`

This will match Eg. http://www.something.com or https://www.something.com  not further `?`  and `/`.

`((?:https?:\/\/)?www\.?[a-zA-Z]+.com\/(?:[^\/]+\/)*)`

This will match Eg. http://www.something.com/some/url or https://www.something.com/some/url

```
<?php
$string='www.domain.com dsa dsad sad sad sa domain.com asdasds adas dsa www.domain.com/someurl/?d sad sadsad www.domain.com/someurl/ asd asd sa www.domain.com?id=123 sd asdsa d';
echo preg_replace("/((?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.com)(?!\/|\?)|(www\.?[a-zA-Z]+.com\/(?:[^\/]+\/)*)/", "$1$2?add_text", $string);
```

Comment: Original data is multi-line, and OP regex was checking for `http://` as well. Looks good otherwise

Comment: Thanks @miken32 ... :D Adding http as well.

Comment: @SERG Welcome   ... :)

Comment: @SERG Welcome   ... :) and accept the post which solves your problem.